# is constexpr const Type necessary in template in order for functions to return compile time const values?

Tags: c++, stl, constants, constexpr, stdarray

looking at the implementation for std::array in c++ i see something i can't quite wrap my head around..

for example, the function that returns the first element in the array is defined as:

```
constexpr const-reference
front() const noexcept
{.......}
```

where const-reference is defined as const value_type&, so the whole expression above evaluates to `constexpr const value_type&`. knowing that in some situations we might want the value returned by the function to be known at compile time, my question is why are they using both `constexpr` and `const` on the same line? isn't the `const` redundant as it was already said that we are going to be returning a `constexpr` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so the whole expression above evaluates to constexpr const value_type&

Not exactly: `constexpr`, for a function/method, mean that the function/method can be executed (also) compile time, not that the returned value is `constexpr`.

> my question is why are they using both constexpr and const on the same line? isn't the const redundant as it was already said that we are going to be returning a constexpr ?

It was redundant in C++11.

`constexpr` was introduced in C++11 and, in C++11, a `constexpr` method was also (necessarily) a `const` method.

This changed starting from C++14 (a good explanation [here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/constexpr-function-is-not-const/))

So, starting from C++14, `consexpr` and `const` (for a method) are decoupled and, as you can see [in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/front), the `std::array::front()` non-`const` version is `constexpr` (starting from C++17).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, this const thing is getting pretty confusing to be honest